# Adicionar vários produtos a uma só encomenda mysql

Tags: php, mysql, query

Boa tarde
Tenho duas tabelas `encomenda` e `prod_encomenda`. O meu objetivo é atribuir para **uma** encomenda **vários** produtos. Ambas contêm o `id_encomenda`, por isso suponho que que a estrutura das tabelas está bem feita!
O que eu pretendo exatamente é por exemplo:

> Encomenda 
> id_encomenda = 1 
>   
>   Prod_encomenda
>   
>   id_produto = 20; id_encomenda=1;
>   id_produto = 42; id_encomenda=1;

Para isso eu fiz algo assim:

```
if (isset($_POST['pagamento']))  //ao carregar no botão efetuar pagamento os dados serão inseridos na tabela encomenda e prod_encomenda
                {
                    //INSERIR NA TABELA ENCOMENDA 
                    $inserir=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO encomenda (id_encomenda,email, data_encomenda) VALUES ('','".$_SESSION['user']."','$data')");
                    if (!$inserir) 
                    {
                        echo "Erro ao inserir na tabela";
                    }

                    $sql2=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT id_encomenda from encomenda where email='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
                    $registos_id_encomenda=mysqli_num_rows($sql2);

                    while ($registos_id_encomenda!=0) {
                        $get_id_encomenda=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
                        $registos_id_encomenda--;
                    }

                    //INSERIR NA TABELA PROD_ENCOMENDA
                    $sql3=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO prod_encomenda (id_encomenda, id_produto, quantidade, preco_total) VALUES ('".$get_id_encomenda[0]."', '$item_id','".$each_item['quantidade']."','$producttotalpricetotal')");
                    if (!$sql3) {
                        echo "Erro ao inserir na tabela";
                    }
```

Só que claramente ao inserir por exemplo 3 produtos, ele gera 3 encomendas na base de dados, em vez de ser só uma encomenda para os 3 produtos.. Obrigada desde já!

Comment: Tens algum ciclo que englobe o código que está dentro do `if (isset($_POST['pagamento']))`? O código do @Nuno Gonçalves é 'mais ou menos' o que terás de fazer. 1. Inserir encomenda; 2. Ir buscar o id gerado usas o `mysqli_insert_id` para isso; 3. Um loop para inserires cada produto que estava no cesto de compras usando como chave estrangeira o tal id do passo 2. Os produtos podem estar na $_SESSION, no $_POST, em $_COOKIES ou até mesmo numa tabela temporária da base de dados, conforme tenhas desenvolvido :)

Comment: Tenho sim @Leite , encontra-se dentro de um `foreach` este é o seguinte código `foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $cada_item) { .... if(isset($_POST['pagamento'])) { ... } }` no meu caso os produtos estão numa sessão!

Comment: Entao é isso :) Esse foreach podes mover para conter apenas a linha `$sql3=mysqli_query(..etc`

Comment: Estás a dizer então que devo eliminar o foreach anterior, e pôr outro só para conter essa linha?

Comment: Sim, estou só a colocar como comentário para ser mais fácil ler.

Comment: O problema é que se eu eliminar esse foreach que se encontra antes do `if(isset)` não me vai gerar mais os produtos, para os poder visualizar :(

Comment: Se quiseres, e se não te importates claro, podemos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78801/discussion-between-ana-and-leite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens algum ciclo que englobe o código que está dentro do `if (isset($_POST['pagamento']))`?

O código do @Nuno Gonçalves é 'mais ou menos' o que terás de fazer.

1. Inserir encomenda;
2. Ir buscar o id com que a encomenda foi guardada (já fazes, mas podes usar o `mysqli_insert_id` para isso em vez de correres uma nova query
3. Um loop para inserires cada produto que estava no cesto de compras usando como chave estrangeira o tal id do passo 2.

Os produtos podem estar na `$_SESSION`, no `$_POST`, em `$_COOKIES` ou até numa tabela temporária da base de dados, conforme tenhas desenvolvido.

Tendo em conta o comentário que deixaste, o que terás de fazer é (remover o ciclo que tens antes do `if` e move-lo para incluir só a execução do `$sql3`

```
$erros = [];
foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $cada_item) {
    //INSERIR NA TABELA PROD_ENCOMENDA
    $sql3=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO prod_encomenda (id_encomenda, id_produto, quantidade, preco_total) VALUES ('".$get_id_encomenda[0]."', '$item_id','".$each_item['quantidade']."','$producttotalpricetotal')");
    if (!$sql3) {
        // como nao é ideal fazer echo aqui
        // podes sempre guardar num array e mais tarde mostrar
        //echo "Erro ao inserir na tabela";
        $erros[] = "Erro ao inserir produto: {$item_id}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Como eu referi, não posso remover o ciclo antes do if, pois não me vai mostrar mais os produtos, teria que alterar o código todo...

Comment: Deixei mensagem no chat. Mas podes repetir o ciclo mais que uma vez.  1 para listar, a outra para inserir na base de dados. Na verdade, o `if (isset($_POST['pagamento']))` podes colocar no topo do teu ficheiro pois só vai ser executado quando o form for submetido.

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente tens que retornar a chave gerada para encomenda submetida e de seguida efectuar um *loop* pelos produtos atribuíndo essa mesma chave. Exemplo:

```
// inserir a encomenda
$sql = "INSERT INTO encomenda (...) VALUES (...)";
mysql_query($sql,$conn );
// retornar o último id
$id_encomenda = mysql_insert_id( $conn );

//percorrer as linhas através do $_POST recebido
foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v) {
    // inserir linhas da encomenda
    $sql = "INSERT INTO prod_encomenda (...) VALUES ($id_encomenda,...))";
    mysql_query($sql,$conn );
}
```

Comment: Através do $_POST? No meu caso estou a usar uma sessão, também serve?

Comment: Claro, @Ana. Basta `foreach($_SESSION AS $key => $value) { ... }`

Comment: Sem sucesso... Ele continua a fazer o mesmo, insere uma encomenda para cada produto...